# Jquery Feed from Input

Tags: jquery, forms, rss, feed, jsfiddle

I'm wondering if someone could show me how to grab the value of an input form and run it through J-query feed to finally dump it in a div.

https://jsfiddle.net/e82fes66/3/

*HTML*

```
<div><input value="Search Here"></input></div>
<div id="feed" class="feed"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
div {margin:25px;}
.feed {width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid #000; overflow-x:hidden;}
```

On the fiddle you'll see an input box and a div with the id 'feed'.. Ideally a user would type in something like cnn.com into the input field & in the #feed div would appear a feed (could add a submit).

Comment: _`#feed` div would appear a feed_ but from where? Welcome to SO, Please formulate your question with clear problem statement.

Comment: Hi Satpal - thanks for the tips. Lets say I type in the search bar www.cnn.com & click submit - what I'm trying to achieve is a JQuery script that puts all the html from www.cnn.com into a div on the same page? is this possible.. cheers, Ryan. :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
<div>
    <input placeholder="Search Here" id="search"/>
</div>
<div id="feed"></div>

$('#search').on('keyup', function(){
   $('#feed').html('<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: Thats pretty cool Krenor - on the right lines. When I type CNN.com in the search bar it appears below - what We're looking for is the rss/html feed from cnn.com in the #feed div? Any thoughts.. cheers!

Comment: You could probably try an AJAX GET request. Maybe there's already an existing plugin for this, as I don't know since I've not worked with RSS feeds yet.